# Не могу разобраться с событиями jquery

Tags: jquery, события

```
$('.location[building-id="0"]').on('click', function () {

    $(this).attr('building-id', 1);

});
```

При клике на элемент с атрибутом равным нулю в него записывается какое-то значение.

**Возникла следующая проблема:**
При повторном клике на этот элемент функция опять выполняется, хотя его атрибут уже не равен нулю. Подскажите, как решить.

PS. на странице много таких же элементов. Функция должна работать повторно, но уже не с теми элементами, в которых атрибут обновлен.

Comment: `$('.location[building-id="0"]').on('click',` потому что вы берете элементы и вешаете на них события. А событие не должно каждый раз проверять на соответствие с селектором, прежде чем запусаться. Позднее атрибуты вовсе можно удалить, как повесли - так и будет работать. А вариант Игоря вешает событие на весь документ и перед кликом проверяет на соответствие с селектором.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).on('click', '.location[building-id="0"]', function () {
```

Comment: а как тогда потом работать с текущим объектом?

Comment: @АлександрЛиссов Он так и будет `this`.

Comment: а не страшно, если я несколько буду событий вешать так на document ?

Comment: @АлександрЛиссов Вы можете повесить это событие на ближайшего родителя, который всегда существует.